# then not working just after fetch in nativescript

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, nativescript

I have one function which calls another function which return promise.
But instead of calling fetch.then(…) it executes next line under function calling and then executes then or catch.
does anyone have idea about this weird behavior?

ex.

```
  isvalidUser = function(uid,pwd)
{
  console.log("first");
  return fetch(config.loginApiUrl + "?uid=" +uid +"&pwd="+pwd)
.then((response) => {
    if(response.ok)
    {
     console.log("second");
    return response.json();
    }else {
        return Promise.reject({status: response.status, data});
      }
}).then(function(data) {

    console.log("data l:" + data.length);
    for(var i=0;i<=data.length;i++)
    {
        console.log("third ");
     viewModel.get("roleId").push(data[i].securityRoleId);
     viewModel.get("UserName").push(data[i].name);
    }
}).catch(handleErrors); 
 } 

 function handleErrors(response) {
if (!response.ok) {
 console.log("inerror");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    throw Error(response.statusText);
}
return response;
```

}
function call on another file

```
    btn_click()
 {
  console.log("execute");
  login.isvaliduser(id,pwd);-----------------------1
  var rid = login.get("roleId").getItem(0);---------------------2
        console.log("role:"+rid);
   }
```

---

console output:
execute

first

role:

second

third

inerror

---

in this case it execute second line first then execute then(…) of validUser()

please help me. It happens in each and every api calls of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **isvaliduser** function you are returning the fetch promise. So you must resolve the promise when you call the function.

You can even add a **catch** after **then** to catch any errors and log them.

```
function btnClick() {
    login.isvaliduser(id,pwd).then(function (whatever) {
      // do whatever you want next
      var rid = login.get("roleId").getItem(0);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this should work. I will try and let you know

Comment: thanks now fetch.then is executing but the problem is it's not going inside of
login.isvaliduser(id,pwd).then(function(){
console.log("this is not printing");
});

Comment: @Radhey.g maybe it's catching an error. add a catch after then. I'll edit my post

Comment: Yes thanks. it's getting error. can you please tell me how to identify those error. if possible as I am newbie to it.

Comment: @Radhey.g depends on the error message. What does it say? Don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks I found the error and also able to resolved it. To upvote i need at least 15 reputation, once i will reach there I will come back and upvote for sure.